# IOS Push Notifications not received or sent anymore for some users

Tags: php, ios, iphone, notifications, push-notification

I've got the following problem.

I have an IOS App which is running since two years and had no problems with the push notifications.

What I basically do is I store all registration ids in a database and send them the notification by a php script:

```
// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

$title = "My App";

$nachricht = $message['teams']['heim']." - ". $message['teams']['aus'];
// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $title. " \n " . $nachricht,
    'sound' => 'default',
    'message' => $nachricht
    );
$body['id'] = $message['spiel'];
$body['message'] = $nachricht;
$body['title'] = $title;

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($registation_ids); $i++) {
    // Build the binary notification
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $registation_ids[$i]) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    // Send it to the server
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

}
fclose($fp);
```

I never had any problems with this script, but now some users who had received notifications some weeks ago aren't receiving them anymore. First I thought there went something wrong with my certificates and provising profiles, but other users with the same IOS version and App version still are receiving the notifications.
I also checked the notification settings of the users not receiving messages anymore and they are correct.

What can cause this problem?
At the moment I don't have any idea where the bug occurs.

Comment: Check the device tokens if registering..

Comment: I don't think they're not registered, because some accounts did receive push notifications some time ago and aren't receiving now. And they can set some settings for they're with the device token as a key, which is also working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function send_notification_ios($registatoin_ids,$message) {

        $ctx = stream_context_create();
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', '');
        //for sandbox url

        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'pemios/dev_apns_vookar.pem');
        $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);

        //for live url

        // stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'pemios/apns-production.pem');
        //$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);

        stream_set_blocking ($fp, 1);
        if (!$fp) {
            echo "Failed to connect (stream_socket_client): $err $errstr";
        }
        else {
            $apple_expiry = time() + (90 * 24 * 60 * 60);
            foreach($registatoin_ids  as $key=>$value){
                $apple_identifier = $key;
                $deviceToken = $value;
                $payload = json_encode($message);
                $msg = pack("C", 1) . pack("N", $apple_identifier) . pack("N", $apple_expiry) . pack("n", 32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . pack("n", strlen($payload)) . $payload;
                fwrite($fp, $msg);
                //checkAppleErrorResponse($fp);
            }
        }
        usleep(500000);
        //checkAppleErrorResponse($fp);
        //mysql_close($con);
        fclose($fp);
        return true;
    }



 $iphonedeviceId = array($requestDataIos[0]['device_id']);
                    $body = array();

                      $body['aps']['alert'] = $message;
                    $body['aps']['userId'] = $params['user_id'];
                    $body['aps']['request_id'] = $params['request_id'];
                    $body['aps']['vendor_id'] = $params['vendor_id'];
                   // $body['aps']['request_vendor_arrived'] = 1;
                    $body['aps']['sender'] = $userDetails[0]['full_name'];


                    $body['aps']['badge'] = +1;
                    $body['aps']['userId'] = $userId;
                    $body['aps']['sound'] = "default";
                    $body['aps']['content-available'] = "1";
                    $body['aps']['nt'] = "3";
                    $this->send_notification_ios($iphonedeviceId, $body);
```

Comment: And check your PEM file

Comment: As some users are receiving the notifications I don't think there is any fault in the PEM file?

Comment: yes ,but  some users are receiving the notifications. then problem in Iphone id

Comment: Am I right that the only relevant difference to my script is the usleep(5000) before closing the $fp?